# Outdated Google Play Console SDK Issue

Tags: android, admob, google-play-console

I've been receiving emails from Google Play Console regarding an old SDK issue for my app. The email states that the com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads SDK version 19.1.0 is outdated.

> The SDK developer com.google.android.gms has reported play-services-ads:19.1.0 as outdated. If you do not upgrade to a newer version, you may not be able to release future versions of your app with this SDK.
>
> Affected version codes:
>
> 9 (2.4.0)

However, this version is from three years ago and the release status is inactive. I've made multiple updates during this time. Also there is no issue in the policy status page.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem or have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue? or just ignore it.

Thanks in advance!